# API PUT request Content-Type

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I'm currently developing the api for my application.
I'm implementing the endpoint to `update` my users table using Postman and every time I send a request with `PUT` and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` only the `_method` field appears when I try to access them through:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

[image]

---

But if I change the content type to `Content-Type: application/json` all my fields appear when I fetch them:
[image]

---

Is the `Content-Type: application/json` the correct one to use with `PUT` requests?
Is there any way I can configure it to accept `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for my `PUT` and `DELETE` requests?

I've searched everywhere in the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4) and [api docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/index.html) and I can't find anything referring the correct content-types to use for each request type.

Comment: What happens when you try the PUT request with POST? Can you see the fields? Are you sure you're encoding/serializing them correctly for the request?

Comment: When I change to POST, laravel doesn't recognize the endpoint I'm trying to reach because there isn't any with the pattern `POST /api/users/{id}`